# php mail function (two buttons ?)

Tags: html, forms

I have the following code in my form:

```
<form action="mail.php" method="POST">
```

Is there a way to add another submit button and let php know that if button1 is used it sends the data to **mail.php** while is button two is used it send the data to **mail2.php** ?

Thanks for the help

Comment: not without some javascript. But you can create two forms pointing at the two scripts quite easily. Or have the ONE php script on the server figure out which button got pushed, and run the appropriate code there. `if ($_POST['submit'] == 'mail2') { include('mail2.php'); }`

Comment: @rid: I see, JavaScript it is then.

Answer (score 0):

It would be correct to use the value of the radio-button, passing the parameter option, like:

```
<input type="radio" name="how" value="mail1" id="radio1"><label for="radio1">Name of parameter1</label>
<input type="radio" name="how" value="mail2" id="radio2"><label for="radio2">Name of parameter2</label>
```

and on the server:

```
$mail = $_POST['how']==mail1?'mail1':'mail2';
include($mail.'.php');
```